# Determining if a system is consistent by examining how b relates to A in Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations

I came across this question in a textbook:

[image]

Previously when working on these sorts of problems, I would convert it to an augmented matrix and row reduce to check if it was consistent, but this question seems to alude to determining if it is consistent simply by looking at the equation $A\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}$, which I am not sure how to do. I'm just curious if I am misinterpereting the question.

Comment: You can take a big shortcut for (a) and (c) by noticing that each row is the same (*except for sign in the first case*) and knowing what that would cause to happen.  You can see at a glance that $\binom{3}{1}$ is not of the form $\binom{k}{-k}$ for (a) and that $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$ is not of the form $\begin{pmatrix}k\\k\\k\end{pmatrix}$.  As for (b) you should be able to tell at a glance that the determinant of $A$ is nonzero and should know what that implies about the consistency of the system.

Answer (score 1):

In this question, you only want to determine whether $b$ is in the column space of matrix $A$ by inspection.

For (a), both columns of $A$ are a multiple of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} $, while $b = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, so obviously $b$ cannot be expressed in terms of the columns of $A$ and it is linearly independent of them.  Hence the system in (a) is inconsistent.

For (b), once can see that adding the columns of $A$ gives $b$, therefore, the system is consistent.

For (c), all three columns of $A$ are along $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ while $b = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ - 1 \end{bmatrix} $.  Clearly $b$ is linearly independent of the columns of $A$, and hence the system is inconsistent.